# Multisite TYPO3 v9, more domains for one rootpage

Tags: typo3, multisite, typo3-9.x

For marketing purposes do I maintain one identical website with two different domains, in TYPO3 v8 I would simply add a domain record on the root page and TYPO3 would take care of the rest with respect to the requested domain (perhaps only a conditional base URL with Typoscript, and a personalised robots.txt for each site trough realurl) ...

With v9 I cannot find a way to do this, I tried to enter a second site definition with yaml manually, but the second one simply does not show up ...

Comment: did my answer help you?

Comment: @Jonas Eberle ... it did ! you got me on the right track at least for the double domain issue; I used condition: 'getenv("HTTP_HOST") == "2nd-domain.tld"' ... but the main issue was the robots file:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59918427/multisite-typo3-v9-distinct-robots-txt-for-multiple-domains-on-one-rootpage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do that with `baseVariants`. This would add a 2nd domain for the production context:

```
baseVariants:
  -
    base: 'https://2nd-domain.tld/'
    condition: 'applicationContext matches "#^Production#" && request.getNormalizedParams().getHttpHost() == "2nd-domain.tld"'
```

Comment: I used: condition: 'getenv("HTTP_HOST") == "2nd-domain.tld"' , but thanks for the pointer, your syntax made me aware of the possibilities !!