# Multisite TYPO3 v9, distinct robots.txt for multiple domains on one rootpage

Tags: yaml, typo3, robots.txt, typo3-9.x

For marketing purposes do I maintain one identical website with two different domains, in TYPO3 v8 I would simply add a domain record on the root page and create a personalised robots.txt with typoscript for each site trough realurl) ...

With v9 I cannot find a way to do this, I tried to enter various anottations in config.yaml manually, but nothing works (i.e. I tried to replicate the annotation for the url)...

```
routes:
  -
    route: robots.txt
    type: staticText
    content: "User-agent: *\r\nDisallow: /"
    contentVariants:
      -
        content: "User-agent: *\r\nAllow: /"
        condition: 'getenv("HTTP_HOST") == "2dn-domain.com"'
```

does anyone know a working annotation, or a different approach ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to stay within the 'regular' solutions so I found a middleground:

in the backend you enter a `Route Type = Page, File or URL [uri]`

with value `t3://page?type=201` so as to address a page type for robots

and with Typoscript you define your conditional robots file:

```
# Theme robots.txt

robots = PAGE
robots {
    typeNum = 201
    config {
        disableAllHeaderCode = 1
        additionalHeaders.10.header = Content-Type:text/plain;charset=utf-8
        xhtml_cleaning = 0
        admPanel = 0
        debug = 0
        index_enable = 0
        removeDefaultJS = 1
        removeDefaultCss = 1
        removePageCss = 1
        INTincScript_ext.pagerender = 1
        sourceopt.enabled = 0
    }

    10 = TEXT
    10.value (
User-Agent: *
Allow: /

# indexed search
User-agent: googlebot
Disallow: /*?tx_indexedsearch

# folders
Disallow: /typo3/
Disallow: /typo3conf/
Allow: /typo3conf/ext/
Allow: /typo3temp/

# parameters
Disallow: /*?id=*                    # non speaking URLs
Disallow: /*&id=*                    # non speaking URLs
Disallow: /*cHash                    # no cHash
Disallow: /*tx_powermail_pi1         # no powermail thanks pages
Disallow: /*tx_form_formframework    # no forms

# sitemap
Sitemap: {$theme.configuration.sitemap}
    )
}

# Adwords Site closed
[globalString = ENV:HTTP_HOST=adw-domain.com]
    robots.10.value (
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /
    )
[global]
```

I also set a constant in constants.typoscript for the seo site:

```
theme.configuration {
    sitemap = /?eID=dd_googlesitemap
    sitemap = http://seo-domain.com/sitemap/seo-domain.xml
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, there is no need to load the robots.txt with all the TYPO3 overhead, except you want to dynamically add content to it.

You can handle multiple robots.txt with Webserver rewrite rules, e.g. with Apache:

```
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots/%{HTTP_HOST}.txt [L]
```

This rule loads the robots.txt depending on HTTP_HOST from a subdirectory:

- robots/domain-a.xy
- robots/domain-b.xy

Comment: that would indeed be a fallback solution, working with a redirect to a robots.php so as to compile and deliver a distintct .txt invisibly